Unable to migrate Prisma
Actually I am learning prisma and using postgresql for the same and my database provider is neon db so when i am trying to migrate my prisma file it is giving me a error and therefore i tried changing my database provider i switched to supabase and used its connection string but still i am getting the same error in my terminal
This is the command i am using on my terminal npx prisma migrate dev --name UsersandTodoAdded
Error i am getting while using supabase is :-
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "postgres.ikepsdfjeftscdpqzakq"
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at postgres.ikepsdfjeftscdpqzakq:5432
Please make sure your database server is running at postgres.ikepsdfjeftscdpqzakq:5432.
ERROR I AM GETTING USING NEONDB IS :-
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "learn-prisma", schema "public" at "ep-green-hat-a1yq4cjh.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech"
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at ep-green-hat-a1yq4cjh.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech:5432
Please make sure your database server is running at ep-green-hat-a1yq4cjh.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech:5432.
I checked my code thoroughly many times and there is no error still i dont know why i am getting this error again and again my internet connection is proper the connection string is also fine still this error is not going.
